# WebView slow loading url

Tags: android, html, ios, webview

To test a url in WebView realize that it takes about 6 ~ 8 seconds to load. Compared to iOS, the WebView takes only 2 seconds. Both devices are on the same wifi network. I am using the following setting in WebView.

```
//Manifest
//android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvProduct);

            final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            }

            //webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
            webView.loadUrl(url);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        } else {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

                webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

            }

        }

public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                                                String urlNewString) {
            view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if(LoadingDialog.instanceProgressDialog().isShowing()) {
                LoadingDialog.dismissDialog();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            if(LoadingDialog.instanceProgressDialog() != null) {

                if (LoadingDialog.instanceProgressDialog().isShowing()) {

                    LoadingDialog.dismissDialog();

                }

            }

            Log.e(Constants.ERROR,
                    "****Error: " + description + " code: " + errorCode);
        }

    }
```

The stranger who removed the WebViewClient that used to remove a loader dialog and won down 2 secounds (4~5) to loading. How can I improve WebView load time, this url is an m-commerce, contains images and javascript. This problem primarily occurs (is deteriorated) in the first charging, ie departing from the activity and return the best thing time is short (3 ~ 4 seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Strangely to add a client to the webview load time increases. When I removed this line time fell 2 seconds.

Comment: in general i guess android web view is to damn slow